# NFSD lock up on FreeNAS 9.3

Tags: nfs, freebsd, truenas, lacp

I have a Dell PowerEdge 2960 running FreeNAS 9.3, and a Dell PowerEdge 1955 Modular Chassis with a 5316M switch.

I wanted to get a faster link between the two so I configured a LAGG with LACP over bce0 and bce1, with the ports on the 5316M configured as channel-group mode auto.

The problem is that this appears to make nfsd go into state D (which I believe is locked in disk wait) on boot up. This state is unkillable which makes it hard to rectify at runtime.

No LAGG, only one link up, or no LACP and it's all golden. It seems that it should be a valid combination though.

Unfortunately this is a production system so it's not easy for me to experiment on (or at least not popular) and to get running I've had to revert to a single link without LAGG.

What am I missing?